# Android studio not asking to open project in new window

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio used to ask me every time I went to open an existing project if I wanted to open this project in a new window but now it doesn't ask and just opens the project in my existing android studio window. So I want to be able to have two projects up at once. Anyone know how to get that prompt to come back up again?

Comment: If you want to occasionally open multiple projects and don't want the popup to show up every time you want to switch between then, you can go to File -> Recent projects -> Manage projects, then click in the gear icon and "open selected". This will open the project in a new window without having to enable that popup.

Answer (score 58):

Windows:

Go to: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening.

macOS:

Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project.

Shortcut (⌘ ,)

Check "Confirm window to open project in"

[image]

now restart your Android Studio

Comment: Oh my god. I looked everywhere in settings for this! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If your issue is solved please mark answer as accepted (green tick)